# htaccess redirect back to HTTP_REFERER for some specific pages

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect to http referer page using mod rewrite htaccess.

For example, a url request is generated from service.html. I want to redirect back to services.html and if a request is generated from portfolio.html redirect back to portfolio.html.

Some one may found it silly, but I am in a problem that the same URL is generated within services and portfolio page that belongs to only them not each other's pages.

Example of link generated are:

> example.com/design.html example.com/market.html

For referer:

> example.com/service.html

While same for portfolio:

> example.com/design.html example.com/market.html

For referer:

> exaple.com/portfolio.html

I think it could be achieved by %{HTTP_REFERER} but I don't know how.

Comment: I have a feeling the rules used to do this will end up into infinite loop. You need to have some condition to bypass the rules. After a url is passed through rules, it is again passed through the rewrite engine internally.  In your case its being passed by you only !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way I understand your question:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} exaple\.com/(service|portfolio)\.html
RewriteRule /(design|market)\.html http://exaple.com/%1.html [redirect,last]
```

The other is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} exaple\.com/service\.html
RewriteRule /design\.html http://exaple.com/service.html [redirect,last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} exaple\.com/portfolio\.html
RewriteRule /market\.html http://exaple.com/portfolio.html [redirect,last]
```

Comment: : thank you for your help, But i could not implement what i want to do, but your suggestions help me, and now i can understand more for these type of issues.